# IlegalStateException when trying to replace the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to display another Fragment when the phone isn't connected to a WiFi network. Normally I'm displaying MainFragment, when no connection is available ErrorFragment.

I'm using `mWifi.isConnected()` to check if there is a connection.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
        new PostTask(1).execute();
    } else {
        MainFragment.firstPageListener.onSwitchToNextFragment();
    }
}
```

This is my code (inside MainFragment) to switch to the ErrorFragment, but it's giving me

```
11-23 20:57:29.588: E/AndroidRuntime(4025): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
```

This is in my MainActivity (I'm using a ViewPager):

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final class FirstPageListener implements FirstPageFragmentListener {
        public void onSwitchToNextFragment() {
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentAtPos0).commit();
            if (mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof MainFragment) {
                mFragmentAtPos0 = new ErrorFragment(listener);
            } else { // Instance of NextFragment
                mFragmentAtPos0 = new MainFragment(listener);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private String[] titles = { "SEARCH", "LIST" };
    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    public Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;
    private Context context;
    FirstPageListener listener = new FirstPageListener();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: // Fragment # 0
            if (mFragmentAtPos0 == null) {
                mFragmentAtPos0 = new MainFragment(listener);
            }
            return mFragmentAtPos0;

        case 1: // Fragment # 1
            return new ListFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof MainFragment && mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof ErrorFragment) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
        if (object instanceof MainFragment && mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof MainFragment) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
        return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }
}

public interface MainFragmentListener {
    void onSwitchToNextFragment();
}
```

I tried to change Fragments with:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager2.beginTransaction();
ErrorFragment fragment2 = new ErrorFragment();
fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack("xyz");
fragmentTransaction2.hide(MainFragment.this);
fragmentTransaction2.add(android.R.id.content, fragment2);
fragmentTransaction2.commit();
```

But when I swipe to the other Tab, the Fragments are overlapping... What should do? Thanks!

(The thumbs down is the ErrorFragment, the Button and On/Off Switch, is in ListFragment)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove
    fragmentTransaction2.hide(MainFragment.this); 
and change 
    fragmentTransaction2.add(android.R.id.content, fragment2); 
to 
    fragmentTransaction2.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment2);